# Converting a string of letters to numbers

Tags: java

Say I have a string `phone = "1-800-test"`

I need to convert the letters to numbers.

Doing something like this doesn't work (note I'm looping it of course):

```
phone = phone.replace(phone.charAt(9), (char) getNumber(phone.charAt(9)));
```

Note that `getNumber()` is a method that takes a letter and returns a number:

```
int getNumber(char uppercaseLetter)
```

Anyway, I get some weird output with the letter replaced by a weird square.

How should I replace the letters with numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing (char)1 gives you the ASCII character represented by 1 so you get the weird square.
You can just use '1' to instead. If you insist on converting integers to ASCII, just add 48 (since that is where the digits start in the ascii). i.e. (char)48 is '0', (char)49 is '1' and so on. That doesn't seem necessary for me though.

The exact answer to your question, is use:

```
phone = phone.replace(phone.charAt(9), (char)(48+getNumber(phone.charAt(9))));
```

But it is NOT recommended...

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option as I'm passing values to a method. I've edited my question for clarity

Comment: I don't really get why, but you CAN just add 48 to the number before casting to char in it would work. i.e. (char)48 is '0' (char)49 is '1' and so on.

Answer (score 10):

(char) 1 is not what you need. You need `'1'`.

The good way to do that is to create a `Map<Character, Character>`, pre-populate it: `map.put('t', '8')`, etc for all letters, and then

```
for (...) {
   Character letter = phone.charAt(i);
   Character digit = map.get(Character.toLowerCase(letter));
   if (digit != null) {
      phone = phone.replace(letter, digit);
   } 
}
```

A trivial solution would be to just have one line for each character:

```
phone = phone.replace('a', '2');
phone = phone.replace('b', '2');
//etc..
```

(or, for better performance, utilize `StringBuilder's` `replace(..)` and `indexOf(..)`)

Comment: Seems pretty complicated for a simple (or so i thought) thing. :S
Is there any easier but less "proper" way of doing it?

Comment: It is rather simple - 5 lines. And there's no simpler way, because you have to be able to replace all characters with their repsective values.

Comment: Of course, you can simply go and have one replace line per char - see my update

Comment: `map.get(Character.toLowerCase());` I think you missed `letter` here.

Comment: @lelouch: I can't think of any better solution than this. Bozho +1.

Comment: Nice solution, but it's abit too complicated for this simple homework question >.<